# Javascript Recursive Function Currying and Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript

This is fine and works:

```
const power = (x,n) => {
  if (n === 0) return 1;
  return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

> power(4,3)
> 64

But trying to do this as experiment - does not work gives NaN
Do not understand why:

> node
> .editor
> // Entering editor mode (Ctrl+D to finish, Ctrl+C to cancel)

```
const power = x => {
  return n => {
    if (n === 0) return 1;
    return x * power(x, n - 1);
  }
}
```

> let t = power(4)
> t(3)
> NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't converted the recursive call in the curried version to curried form. `power(x, n - 1)` is essentially the same as `power(x)` because `power` only accepts one argument, and this is a function, so not unreasonably becomes `NaN` when you try to multiply it by a number.

Rewrite it like this instead:

```js
const power = x => {
  return n => {
    if (n === 0) return 1;
    return x * power(x)(n - 1);
  }
};

console.log('4^3 = ', power(4)(3));     // 64
console.log('2^10 = ', power(2)(10));   // 1024
console.log('5^4 = ', power(5)(4));     // 625
console.log('3^4 = ', power(3)(4));     // 81
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the nested function and return the function and use this function for another call with only the changed `n`.

```js
const
    power = x => {
        const
            fn = n => n === 0
                ? 1
                : x * fn(n - 1);

        return fn;
    };

console.log(power(4)(3));
```

Comment: Is that Tab before "power" on purpose?  Looks weird xd

Comment: @JesúsGuillénYparrea, yes it is, because `const` is only the lead in of the statement and the indentation is the listing of variables.

Comment: i see... I have never seen that style before, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

As we are discussing "weird" function forms I might as well contribute my two cents worth:

You can also do the curried function as a one-liner like this:

```js
const power = (x,pow) => pow = n => --n ? x*pow(n) : x;

console.log(power(3)(4)); // 81
```

This is, of course, something that nobody in their right mind would ever do. Still - it works!